# How can I get colored output with printf and Perl's Term::ANSIColor?

Tags: perl, colors, printf

is there a way to get with `printf` colored output?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; 
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;

printf "%4.4s\n", colored( '0123456789', 'magenta' );
```

Output: (only newline)

> 

Comment: @ niry and murugaperumal: I need printf "%4.4s\n"

Comment: That's a different question from "way to get `printf` colored output". at this point in time you have the answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume you want something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor;

print colored( sprintf("%4.4s", '0123456789'), 'magenta' ), "\n";
```

Answer (score 11):

> You need to change your code like the
>   following

```
printf "%s\n", colored( '0123456789', 'magenta' );
```

> Because we can't get the first 4
>   character in the string. If you give
>   the string value to the printf
>   function it will print the value up to
>   null character. We can't get the first
>   4 characters.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is "%4.4s\n" try "%s\n" it will work. the reason is that colors are chars (escape chars) and you are cutting them. try printf "%s\n", length(colored( '0123456789', 'green' )); to understand better.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to print colored output can be

```
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
print RED, "Stop!\n", RESET;
print GREEN, "Go!\n", RESET;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use colors in print do the folowing:

`use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);`

And then use the specific colors names.

For example:
If you want to print text in green bold color, use:
`print GREEN BOLD "Passed", RESET;`.

The `RESET` resets the color back to normal.

If you want to print text in red blinking color, use:
`print BLINK BOLD RED "Failed!", RESET;`

If you want to display a progress bar for example using a green "box", use:
`print ON_GREEN " ", RESET;`

Another twik: if you want to reposition the cursor accross the screen, use:
`print "\033[X;YH";` where X is line pos and Y is column pos, for exmple: `print "\033[5;7H";`

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution to preserve the space alignment when print multiple value (eg. from DB):

```
print sprintf("%-10s %-32s %-10s\n",
  $row->{id},
  $row->{name},
  ($row->{enabled} ? colored(sprintf("%-10s", 'Enabled'), 'GREEN') : 'Disabled'),
);
```